# Simple Html Dom Parser not working with http://www.estelleblogmode.com/

Tags: php, html-parsing

I tried to read content from http://www.estelleblogmode.com/ but I can't read.
The other urls work but I can't get some of urls content like http://www.estelleblogmode.com/.
Does anybody knows solution?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you mean I can't get content from this url? is there no solution?

Comment: I mean, you haven't explained what you mean by "it doesn't work."

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it causes error like this. " Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.estelleblogmode.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in F:\wamp\www\Tag\simple_html_dom.php on line 75"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use this site with dom parser.
You are right.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of dom parser problem.